# looking for an alternative to python for processing speed: 2D quantum particle

Tags: java, python, c++, octave

I have a program written in Python that accurately shows the time evolution of a quantum particle in both 1 and 2 dimensional wells.  I am too lazy to post the entire thing online, but I will be happy to email the source to anyone willing to take a look.

My question is this: Is there a faster way? This thing should look like it's going crazy in its box, not calmly gliding around.  When you run the program, choose "yes" on the realtime option to get a diagnostic of the performance.  It runs at about 3 dt steps (on the order of 10<sup>-6</sup> to 10<sup>-18</sup> seconds) per actual real second.  Needless to say, by the time this program shows me what has happened to the particle after 1 second of real time, I will be old and grey.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like an interesting question, but unfortunately I am too lazy to post an entire answer

Comment: Profile your existing code with cProfile. That will tell you what the bottlenecks are. Consider what you can do to optimise the functions which take up most of the program time. You may be able to optimise in Python, or you may need to write C code just for those functions.

Comment: If there is a way to post the program?  I am new with this forum, and have not yet found an upload function.

Comment: Also, have you tried using PyPy? If you're using Python 2.7, then PyPy will probably give you a substantial increase in speed. If you're using a significantly earlier version of Python, try psyco. If you're using Python 3.x, can you wait for PyPy3 to be released?

Comment: Currently using python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

> It runs at about 3 dt steps (on the order of 10^-6 to 10^-18 seconds) per actual real second. Needless to say, by the time this program shows me what has happened to the particle after 1 second of real time, I will be old and grey. Any suggestions?

If you are lucky, you *might* get a factor of 10 to 100 speed-up by changing language implementations or languages.  But it sounds like you want *many* orders of magnitude faster performance.  For that you would need:

- a fundamental change in the algorithms you are using, and / or
- using a computation platform with lots of hardware parallelism.

This kind of computational problem doesn't have simple solutions.